# How to create and query table containing lat/long using PostGIS?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

How would I create a table that contains a geography point (lat/long) using PostGIS? Then also, what would the format be for inserting into this table (Using SQL/PostgreSQL)?

Would it just the following for table creation:

`CREATE TABLE x (geog geography(point, 4326))`

If so, what is the `point` and when would you instead use `ST_Point(X,Y)`

Should this column have an index?

Note: Many questions previously answered detail how to convert. But I want to create an empty table from scratch that supports storing latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Syntax for Creating a table with Geography is as simple as `CREATE TABLE x (geog geography(POINT,4326) );`

In this Command, `POINT` is the type of shape that this table will be storing. Other possibilities are :

- LINESTRING
- POLYGON
- MULTIPOINT
- MULTILINESTRING
- MULTIPOLYGON
- GEOMETRYCOLLECTION

The reason why storing a Geography in a table makes sense in some cases, is that it gives you the ability to run [several functions](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch08.html#PostGIS_GeographyFunctions) which would give you results as if you are calculating on a Spherical Earth. So for example I could have two points stored as Geography (knowing only lat-long of each), and I could easily find the distance between them in Meters

`ST_Point(X,Y)` is just a function that takes in two numbers, and then creates a point which has X as the first number and Y as the second number. It need not be a Lat-long pair. Infact this Point has not concept of which Coordinate reference system it is in.

Once you create the table, inserting records in it, is as simple as:
`INSERT INTO X (geog) VALUES (ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(2.5559 49.0083)'));`

Here You are are creating a Geography point for Paris, with latitude of 49.0083N and longitude of 2.5559 E